# ajax request aborted before specified timeout

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using ajax to fetch data from server.
If I don't receive any response from server within the specified time; then I want to execute a timeout handler. I need to set this timeout value to 60 seconds.
But I see different behaviour for different browsers as below:

IE9 will execute timeout handler if specified timeout is upto 40 seconds.
If the timeout value is increased to 60; IE9 does not execute timeout handler.
In IE9 debuggging tool, I see the request getting aborted after 40 seconds  even though timeout is specified as 60 seconds.

Same occurs for mozilla.

Chrome will execute timeout handler if specified timeout is upto 20 seconds.
If the timeout value is increased to 30; chrome does not execute timeout handler.

Here is how I am sending the ajax requests:

```
 http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 http_request.open('GET', url, true);

 http_request.ontimeout = function()
 { 
   timeoutaction(http_request); // function to execute when timeout occurs

 };


 http_request.onreadystatechange = function() 
 { 
      processContents(http_request); // function to execute onreadystatechange 
 };


 http_request.timeout = 60000;// Timeout value -- 60 seconds

 http_request.send(null);
```

Thanks,

Swapnil

Comment: Can you add the following if condition in your **readystatechange** event and see if you have different results: `if (http_request.readyState === 4) { processContents(http_request); }`

Comment: @istos I alreeady have this if condition inside processcontents() function:if (http_request.readyState == 4) 
   { 
      if (http_request.status == 200){}   }

Comment: Is there any solution for this issue? Or some differnt approach that I should try to fix this? Please let me know if you have any suggestions.